# Definition of regular languages using fsm

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

I went across the definition of regular languages and i found this property:

> A language is said to be regular if and only if some FSM recognizes it

and as an example :

> {a^n, b^m} isn't a regular language..

However I think this can be represented using the following DFA :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NiHY.png

Any explanation on where I'm wrong is so welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: The language your FSM accepts is `(a|b)*`, which is a superset of `a^nb^m`. More importantly, without constraints on `n` or `m`, `a^nb^m` is also regular (it can be matched by the regular expression `a*b*`). If there is a constraint such as `n <= m`, or `2m = n`, then the language is less likely to be regular.

Comment: Exactly what i needed to know :D Thank you